# IOS App Hanging on cell declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode7

The program runs for `indexPath.row == 0` but going into a memory loop when executing the `indexPath.row` not equal 0.  This worked previously before Xcode 7.0.  This is also a multi target app but both targets are showing for all .m and storyboard.  When running I get the "Event Cell 0", "Event Cell 1" and "Event Cell 2" and then it stops on the declaration for `EventViewCell`.  I have deleted and recreated the cell, but nothing works.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Event Cell 0");

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        EventCreateCell *cell = (EventCreateCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventCreateCell"];
        cell.createButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        NSLog(@"Event Cell 1");
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Event Cell 2");
        EventViewCell *cellEvent = (EventViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventViewCell"];
        NSLog(@"Event Cell 2-0");

        Calendar *calendar = [self.dataModel.calendardata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
        NSLog(@"Event Cell 2-1");
        cellEvent.textField.text = calendar.calendarText;
        cellEvent.textDetailField.text = calendar.calendarDetailText;
        cellEvent.startDateTextField.text = calendar.calendarStartDate;
        cellEvent.endDateTextField.text = calendar.calendarEndDate;
        NSLog(@"Event Cell 2-2");

        return cellEvent;
    }
}

//
//  EventViewCell.h
//  MyAssociation
//
//  Created by Donald Ewing on 9/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Donald Ewing. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EventViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *startDateTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *endDateTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textDetailField;

@end

//
//  EventViewCell.m
//  MyAssociation
//
//  Created by Donald Ewing on 9/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Donald Ewing. All rights reserved.
//

#import "EventViewCell.h"

@implementation EventViewCell

@synthesize textField;
@synthesize startDateTextField;
@synthesize endDateTextField;
@synthesize textDetailField;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Please show the `EventViewCell` class

Comment: 1. What is your question? 2. Show vc with this table in storyboard.

Comment: You're dequeuing two different types of table views. Are you sure the EventViewCell identifier is set? Are you sure EventViewCell inherits from the correct classes?

Comment: If it is in a loop you can place a breakpoint in the loop and then single step watching the variables to figure out why.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not calling [super awakeFromNib] in EventViewCell?  You're preventing that cell from waking up, I suspect.  Since you're not doing anything in there anyway, I would just delete that method.  Also, check that you have all the outlets hooked up and that the dequeueing identifier is set.

Comment: The question is how can it fix this code so it will display the tables.  I set a breakpoint and the information looks correct.  I have other tableview in the program that work correctly.  This one stopped working when I went to Xcode 7 and IOS 9

Comment: Also, If I delete the  data file that populates the tableview the app does hangup, only when there is data to display.

Comment: Also, If I delete the  data file that populates the tableview the app does not hangup, only when there is data to display.

Comment: Found the solution on the Apple Forum.  There is an error in Xcode 7 that when you put sample text in a text view in a prototype cell the load causes the app to hangup.